# Visual studio вылетает с ошибкой

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

При работе с user controls на каком-то моменте работы начинает вылетать студия при загрузке графического интерфейса. Подскажите в чем может быть причина. Уже дня мучаюсь, не могу продолжить работу над проектом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

1. Запустите Command Prompt от имени администратора.
2. Введите следующие команды, нажмите Enter после каждой строки.

```
regsvr32 atl.dll
cd C:\WINDOWS\eHome
ehSched /unregServer
ehSched /service
ehRecvr /unregServer
ehRecvr /service
ehRec.exe /unregServer
ehRec.exe /regserver
ehmsas.exe /unregServer
ehmsas.exe /regserver
```

или

> 1.devenv.exe /safemode
>
> 2.devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
>
> 3.devenv.exe /installvstemplates
>
> 4.devenv.exe /resetsettings
>
> 5.devenv.exe /resetuserdata

Comment: Попробовал оба варианта - не помогло.